# Error deploying java google app engine flexible application - Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

Writing this issue as I have no idea how to investigate it.

We're having problems in deploying an app engine flexible application.
The problem is, that the only error we get is the following:

***GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.***

I tried already the following:

- Try a simple helloWorld app, to make sure it's not an application issue
- Check quota settings -> All green
- Check activity stream for warnings or errors
- Check logs for warngings or errors
- Grant owner role to service account which is deploying the app

**App.yaml:**

```
service: test-service # Id of the service
env: flex       # Flex environment
runtime: java   # Java runtime
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8 # use OpenJDK 8
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2.8
```

**gcloud version**

```
Google Cloud SDK 214.0.0 alpha 2018.08.24 
app-engine-java 1.9.64
app-engine-python 1.9.74 beta 2018.08.24 bq 2.0.34
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.0.2 
core 2018.08.24 
gsutil 4.33 
kubectl 2018.08.24 
pubsub-emulator 2018.08.24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting the google technical support, we found out, that the default app engine service account didn't have the Editor role. After assigning the editor role the deployment worked again.

Answer (score 0):

This error is often reported when your application has reached the quota limit for ["In-use IP addresses"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#ip_addresses). Similar error was reported on this Google Cloud Platform [issue link](https://issuetracker.google.com/72937428). The default value for the in-use addresses is '8', and this quota value can be increased clicking the ['Edit' button in the Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) — Ensure you are editing the value for In-use IP addresses.

The Google engineer confirmed that there is a planned improvement to the quota error details to be implemented in one of the next versions of gcloud SDK. You can track updates on the CloudSDK within this [Google Group link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sdk-announce)

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned, the quota settings look good... We have 69 available in use addresses and only 4 are used.